# Calculus of residues

Tags: residue-calculus

How can we find the residue at $ z=0 $ of 
$$f(z) = \log\left(\frac{1-az}{1-bz}\right)$$
where $a, b$ are complex constants?

Answer (score 0):

Note that as $z\to 0$,
$$f(z) = \log\left(\frac{1-az}{1-bz}\right)=\log\left(1+\frac{(b-a)z}{1-bz}\right)=(b-a)z+ o(z)$$
What may we conclude? Recall that the residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the expansion of $f$ at $0$.

Comment: is it not $\frac{(b-a)z}{1-bz}+o(z)$?

Comment: @vidyarthi At the first order they are the same!

Comment: so is the residue $0$?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, the residue at 0 is 0. BTW if you are new here take a few seconds for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour